# Convert nested for-loop to lambda function for fast execution

Tags: python, performance, lambda, nested-loops

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSJNJ.png)

Hi, My Data frame looks like the attached image. 
Nbr_Cells column is a list of objects. I am trying to add another column in the data frame which is a sublist of Nbr_Cells column if the individual object ends with the same end of column cellid.

For example,

> cellid = U21-A000CH-1A
>   Nbr_Cells =[U21-MCH001-1A,U21-MCH001-2A,U21-SG0024-1A,U21-MCH001-2B]
>
> Then sublist = [U21-MCH001-1A,U21-SG0024-1A]

since it ends with similar "1A" ending. 
Similarly, this has to be replicated for each row.

I have written following code with for loop and its working fine. But it's taking a lot of time to execute. 
Need help in converting the same to lambda function or any similar fast execution code.

```
for j in range(0,len(Overall_list)):
    print(j)
    List = []
    for i in Overall_list['Nbr_Cells'][j]:
        if(i.split("-")[2] == Overall_list['cellid'][j].split("-")[2]):
            List.append(i)
    Overall_list['Sub_Nbr_List'][j] = List
```

Answer (score 0):

The main bottleneck in your code is that you are evaluating `Overall_list['cellid'][j].split("-")[2]` multiple times when you could get that matching value only once outside of the nested loop.  It is generally faster to iterate over items rather than referencing items by index.  Also, you can use a list comprehension instead of a second loop:

```
for j,list_item in enumerate(Overall_list):
    print(j)
    match = list_item['cellid'].split("-")[2]
    List  = [ i for i in list_item['Nbr_Cells'] if i.split("-")[2] == match ]
    list_item['Sub_Nbr_List'] = List
```

Comment: That totally makes sense Alain. Thanks for your response. This works perfectly well. Also i tried using the similar logic to do the match case outside the loop in below function.. 

`def function(a,b):
    List = []
    for i in a:
        try:
            if(i.endswith(b)):
                List.append(i)
        except:
            List = []
    return List
Overall_list['Sub_Nbr_List'] = Overall_list.apply(lambda x: function(x.Nbr_Cells,x.Pattern), axis =1)`